# after changing to XML "cereal could not find any output serialization functions"

Tags: c++, serialization, cereal

I want to serialize a Reconstruction class in a library called theia. The class Reconstruction does have a serialize function:

```
friend class cereal::access;
  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar) {  // NOLINT
    ar(next_track_id_,
       next_view_id_,
       view_name_to_id_,
       views_,
       tracks_);
  }
```

The serialization already in place works fine like this:

```
Reconstruction estimated_reconstruction;

[...]
std::ofstream output_writer(output_file, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
cereal::PortableBinaryOutputArchive output_archive(output_writer);
 output_archive(estimated_reconstruction);
```

But when I change it to an XMLOutputArchive (adding the necessary #include) it doesn't work anymore!

```
Reconstruction estimated_reconstruction;
[...]

std::ofstream output_writer(output_file, std::ios::out);
cereal::XMLOutputArchive output_archive(output_writer);
output_archive(estimated_reconstruction);
```

The error is the following one:

[...]

```
error: static assertion failed: cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination.

 Types must either have a serialize function, load/save pair, or load_minimal/save_minimal pair (you may not mix these).
 Serialize functions generally have the following signature:

 template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive & ar)
   {
     ar( member1, member2, member3 );
   }
```

Comment: To see where the problem is coming from, try serializing the class members  one at a time. You can then debug that individual class with XML serialization.

Comment: Does the compiler create any additional output around this error?  I have found I get this error when I forget to add a header that includes my Load/Save functions, and typically the place I need to add that header is indicated at the end of a long chain of "see reference to:".  In visual studio, this appears in the output window.